# Concurrency exception in Entity Framework when loading and deleting objects

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, entity-framework

I've got an EF class mapped to a SQL Server table.  I have the following very simple Entity Framework code (using the ASP.NET Boilerplate repository wrapper over the EF DBContext):

```
var objectsToDelete = repository.GetAll().Where(r => r.parentId == param1).ToList();
foreach(var obj in objectsToDelete) {
    repository.Delete(obj); //doesn't actually update the database yet.
}
...
repository.SaveChanges();
```

Note that the GetAll call will immediately read from the database.

Surprisingly to me, this is a real concurrency headache when multiple web service calls try to run this code simultaneously with the same param1 value (imagine that the user performs the exact same action twice in quick succession).  To cut a long story short, a context switch can occur between getting the IDs and calling SaveChanges.  So this is what happens (you can change this order around quite a bit without affecting the result):

1. Thread #1 starts a SQL transaction and starts running the above code.
2. Thread #2 starts a SQL transaction and starts running the above code (using a different DBContext).
3. Thread #1 gets the objects to delete.
4. Context switch.
5. Thread #2 gets the objects to delete - they will have the same IDs that #1 read.
6. Thread #2 marks the objects as deleted and calls SaveChanges, which issues the SQL DELETE statements.
7. Thread #2 commits its transaction and it's done.
8. Thread #1, using its (now stale) list, marks those same objects as deleted and calls SaveChanges, which issues the SQL DELETE statements.
9. Exception!  Entity throws this:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).

Now, even if I turn the transaction isolation level all the way up to Serializable, this doesn't help.  "Serializable" specifies that statements cannot read data that has been modified but not yet committed by other transactions.  But the problem occurred in step 5, and at that point nothing had been modified.  Ah, but Serializable also specifies that no other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current transaction until the current transaction completes.  Okay, so in the above sequence Thread #2 will block at step 6.  But that just shifts the problem without addressing it.  Whichever thread is the second one to attempt the delete will encounter the 'unexpected rowcount' exception.

I can't see any prevention - only treatment.  It seems that I have to either swallow the exception or turn off Entity Framework's validation-on-save.  And since I'm using ASP.NET Boilerplate, that doesn't seem to be very convenient.  I’m puzzled that something so apparently simple and typical isn’t easier to control.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are all calls to `repository` going though the same `Context` instance regardless of thread?

Comment: No, each thread gets its own `repository` and `Context`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var objectsToDelete = repository.GetAll().Where(r => r.parentId == param1).ToList();
if(objectsToDelete.Count!=0)
{
    repository.RemoveRange(objectsToDelete ); 
}
...
repository.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I don’t see how this helps.  We still have the problem that, after you get objectsToDelete, another thread can delete them and call SavesChanges before you do.  When you call SaveChanges you will get the unexpected row count exception.